Trying to update pytest.ini file during runtime but the settings are not picked up for the same test execution instance
`I'm trying to update pytest.ini file during runtime (Wanted the log folder to pick up current date and time as a file name) but the settings are not picked up for the same test execution.
For example, If I'm updating pytest.ini file using below code, It just updates the pytest.ini file but that pytest configurations are not being applied for the same run. I have to rerun my tests to get the configuration. And by that time the time is changed.
def settings_configure():
config = ConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
config['pytest'] = {
    'log_cli': 'true',
    'log_level': 'DEBUG',
    'log_format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s)',
    'log_date_format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    'log_file': "./logs/" + current_time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d') + ".txt",
    'log_file_date_format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    'log_file_mode': 'a',
    'addopts': '-rA',
    'logging_on': 'TRUE'
}
with open('pytest.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
config.read('pytest.ini')

and I'm calling above function under the method pytest_configure like below.
def pytest_configure(config):
return settings_configure()
How do I update pytest.ini during runtime and use those configurations for the same instance?
Tried to use it as a fixture as well as hook. none worked. Please help.`

You can edit pytest.ini during execution and expect pytest to pick up the changes. The file is read once at test start and then munged together with other settings from environment variables or command line options.
There is, however, experimental support for dynamically configuring the logging-plugin.
conftest.py
import pytest

# without trylast=True, this function is run before the logging-pluggin is loaded,
# and so fails to work as expected 
@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    logging_plugin = config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('logging-plugin')
    logging_plugin.set_log_path('custom.log')

test file
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('my-test')

def test_foo():
    log.info('testing')

Run as:
pytest --log-file-level=DEBUG

Alternatively, add the log_file_level option to your pytest.ini file.
Without pytest support
Just add a wrapper script to run your tests that adds the appropriate flag.
run-tests.sh
#!/bin/bash
pytest --log-file="logs/$(date +%Y_%m_%d).txt" --log-file-level=DEBUG "$@"

